# How to use vpnc on Ubuntu with smart card authentication

Tags: vpnc

Has anyone done this successfully?  I've been using vpnc to work remotely for one of my major clients and they've recently added the restriction that the connection must be authenticated with a smart card.  I really don't want to have to go back to using Windows to do all my work for them.

Answer (score 1):

vpnc is pretty ancient, try openconnect instead.

http://www.infradead.org/openconnect/index.html

it supports smartcards